# Determine if sequence has started

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

If you create a sequence as:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TestSequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 5
NO CYCLE;
```

if you look at the record in `sys.sequences` you see a `start_value` of `1` and a `current_value` of `1`.

If you then retrieve a value with:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR TestSequence;
```

You get the value `1`. But if you again look at the record, the `current_value` is still `1`. It's only when you retrieve a second value, getting `2`, that `current_value` becomes `2`.

In fact, creating two identical sequences as above, and selecting one value from the first and none from the second, there is no difference between the two sequence rows (aside from different timestamps/IDs). How can I tell that one of them has begun and the other has not?

One reason this is a problem is that I cannot rely on `current_value` to be either of a "last value" or "next value", since it starts out as "next" but then immediately becomes "last". What I may need to do is just throw away the first value, and then `current_value` would hopefully consistently mean "last value".

Comment: Is it possible that you're putting too much significance in the specific values your sequences are outputting and whether they've "started" or not? What is your reason for doing this?

Comment: @alroc other than understanding how the sequence works, which was really confusing when the field keeps changing meaning, (ok, current is the next value and start is exclusive; no wait start is inclusive; no wait current is the last value? or is it? what?) just feedback to the user, showing what the sequence they've selected looks like, including an expected next value.

Comment: But you can't make a valid guess at the "expected next value" because as soon as user A gets a value (or you report to User A what you expect to be the next value), user B may get the next value. Again, are you putting too much significance on these values?

Comment: @alroc that's why it's "expected" next value and not "guaranteed" next value. it just shows the user how things are. If there are only 10 or so numbers that can be retrieved, it's important to see that it's at 2 rather than 8, for example. I'm just trying to do so in a way that the meaning doesn't change.

Comment: I agree that you seem to be putting way too much effort into what is effectively as estimated number in the first place. Since you already know it is the "expected" next value why not just roll with it and not worry about it. So what if two people get 1 as the expected next value and one of them actually gets 2? Why does this matter?

Comment: @SeanLange Why shouldn't consistency matter? Being able to know that the field always means the same thing is important. I don't think you would be saying this if there was an easy way for it to be consistent.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you care? It isn't about consistency. After the second value is behaves like you want it to. You can't directly modify the system view anyway so this is all about the initial seed for a sequence. I just don't see any significance to why this matters.

Comment: @SeanLange Without a solution I just have to accept the fact that the "expected next value" is the same for a sequence that hasn't generated a value as for one that has generated exactly one value. I don't see why that shouldn't matter except that people never like admitting when there isn't a good solution for something. Anyways, I have a workaround now and it works exactly like I would like it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this is to always pull and ignore the first value when creating (or restarting) a sequence. You end up with consistent meanings for the properties then.

You then need to treat `MAXVALUE`/`maximum_value` as an exclusive value (ie, add one to it).

You also need to subtract one from the values you get back.

(If you were to use increments other than 1, you'd need to add or subtract the increment instead.)

So, to set up a sequence that yields 1-5, with a reliable reading of what the current value actually is:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE OneToFiveSequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 6
NO CYCLE;

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR OneToFiveSequence;
```

And then when retrieving values, something like:

```cs
var sql = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR OneToFiveSequence;";
var result = ExecuteScalar<long>(sql) - 1;
return result;
```

Then you can correctly create a sequence, see that the next value should be 1, get a 1, see that the next value should be 2, get a 2, etc.